# Skyrim PyAutoGUI (PyDirectInput)

Tags: key, mouse, pyautogui

I honestly don't know how to fix that problem

I'm trying to move my cursor with PyDirectInput module (almost the same as PyAutoGUI, but the last one usually not works in the games)

```
pydirectinput.move(0,1) # x and y
```

The problem is in desktop the movements are ok, pixel by pixel

When I turn on Skyrim, it inputs 1 pixel movement as like 200 pixels and I don't know how to fix it.
I've tried to jiggle mouse sensitivity, and skyrimprefs.ini parameters but it doesn't seem to be useful